# Customization required while downloading shapefile from Geoserver

Tags: geoserver

By default, Geoserver outputs shapefile in ZIP file format. I need help with 2 points:

1. How can I avoid wfsrequest.txt file in shapefile, which have request query?
2. How can I choose attributes to download?

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there is a way to do 1 but 2 is easy, as the [WFS reference](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wfs/reference.html) (or the [WFS standard](http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/wfs)) point out you can specify the attributes you wish returned in your `getFeature` request.

> To restrict a GetFeature request by attribute rather than feature, use the `propertyName` key in the form `propertyName=attribute`. You can specify a single attribute, or multiple attributes separated by commas. To search for a single attribute in all features, the following request would be required:

```
http://example.com/geoserver/wfs?
  service=wfs&
  version=2.0.0&
  request=GetFeature&
  typeNames=namespace:featuretype&
  propertyName=attribute
```

Comment: Yes, there is presently no way to remove the wfsresponse.txt file. Pull requests to make this configurable welcomed!

Comment: Also I can't see any harm in the wfsresponse.txt file anyway.

Comment: Thinking out loud, if they are using authkey as the auth mechanism, the file will contain the key.

Comment: Our Geoserer runs on private IP and main server internally communicates with that. We can't let user know IP address or geoserver request, which is internal mechanism.

Comment: See this if you want to make the presence of that file configurable, it would be a new feature: https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/wiki/Successfully-requesting-and-integrating-new-features-and-improvements-in-GeoServer